# prove that $\sin^2θ(1 + \sec^2 θ) = \sec^2 θ - \cos^2 θ$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove that

$\sin^2θ(1 + \sec^2 θ) = \sec^2 θ - \cos^2 θ$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: we have $$\sin(\theta)^2+\tan(\theta)^2=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)^2}-\cos(\theta)^2$$ and now use that $$\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)^2}=\frac{\sin(\theta)^2+\cos(\theta)^2}{\cos(\theta)^2}$$